# How do I preform an action, after a brief pause?

Tags: android, dialog, callback

I have an app that crops faces - something the app can do in a nanosecond, but I want the user to think it takes a bit longer.  So in a case on a button click, Here is what I have:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "",
                        "Cropping faces...", true);
                dialog.show();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 3000);
                            cropFaces();
                            return
```

}

The dialog shows fine and the faces crop fine too.  The problem is - when the user runs the app, the two happen simultaneously on the screen.

Is there a way to make it so the dialog appears, 3 seconds elapse on screen, and then the cropFaces runs?  That way it will look like it cropped the faces in a few seconds and then the new page appears.  Thanks!

Comment: should basically work. try putting the handler outside the onClick. Put the Handler as a field of the activity. I am not sure, but maybe the handler runs the postdelayed too early because it is cleaned up after the onclick method was processed? (just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your call to `cropFaces()` inside your `run()` method, so it is delayed as well.